# Access printer from ionic2

Tags: cordova, angular, typescript, ionic2

I  would  like  to know. is  there  any option to implement  Print/connect printer
from ionic 2 .Is  there  any  cordova  plugin to Print .
I  came  across  this plugin.

[Cordova Print plugin](https://github.com/katzer/cordova-plugin-printer)

any  help/Info regarding  this  will  be useful.Is  there any  way  to  access third party libraries in Ionic 2.??

Answer (score 1):

In Ionic 2 you can use Ionic Native with the Cordova printer plugin to print either to a PDF file or to a real paper .The steps to follow are easy .
First add the Cordova plugin for printing with

```
cordova plugin add https://github.com/katzer/cordova-plugin-printer.git
```

Next import classes

```
import {Printer, PrintOptions} from 'ionic-native';
```

Then add this method to your class

```
    print(){

        Printer.isAvailable().then(function(){
            Printer.print("https://www.techiediaries.com").then(function(){
            alert("printing done successfully !");
            },function(){
            alert("Error while printing !");
            });
        }, function(){
        alert('Error : printing is unavailable on your device ');
        });

}
```

To test the method add a button to your template

```
       <button class="button" (click)="print()">Print</button>
```

You can find the complete tutorial [here](https://www.techiediaries.com/mobiledev/how-to-print-with-ionic2-and-cordova/)

Answer (score 0):

Cordova Print Plugin ,

```
cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-printer
```

cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-printer
Or a specific version:

```
cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-printer@VERSION
```

And then execute:

```
cordova build
```

https://github.com/katzer/cordova-plugin-printer

Comment: what  type  of  printers  does  this plugin  support? can  u  elaborate  how to  implement  this.?

Comment: https://github.com/katzer/cordova-plugin-printer/blob/example/images/print-ios.png

Comment: The plugin and its methods are not available before the deviceready event has been fired.

document.addEventListener('deviceready', function () {
    // cordova.plugins.printer is now available
}, false);